# What is the UIElement of the iOS's mail client?

Tags: ios, email, uielement

[image: http://zapt3.staticworld.net/images/article/2012/09/ios6-mail-thum-100004989-large.jpg]

As you can see the iOS Mail client can see some rich emails, so, it seems that it is not a TextArea, what is the Mail Client using? A UIWebView? or something custom make? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Emails contain HTML content, which is always rendered in a `WebView` no matter what modern email client you use, so yes, it is a `UIWebView`.

Answer (score 0):

It can not be any default `UIElement`. I think it is a customised view